# How to apply a grayscale to html elements that include more than images in IE11?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

All of the questions and answers I have found only address images. I have an existing div that has images and text that include different backgrounds and text colors. For modern browsers I can easily use CSS3 to apply a grayscale filter to the entire element which works perfect. What I cant do is get the same for IE11. I have found ways of doing so that affect only the images, but due to the complexity of other elements I am seeking a generic solution to an element that includes both images and text.

I've tried to use an SVG filter on the  but that seems like it is not supported at all. I'd rather not need to target every single type of element.

I'm looking for a solution that will cover images, icons, text with backgrounds of different colors and different colored text.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: SVG Masking seems to work https://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-masking-examples-2/

Comment: This browser doesn't support filtering HTML elements nor does it support SVG `<foreignObject>` element. So three options: render your whole page as image (e.g using html2canvas lib), but it's a heck of a perf killer and not really scalable. Convert your page to SVG, probably a lot of work, and SVG is not really more dynamic than a raster image (at least for texts). So maybe the best would be to use what you found for images, and for non image to set it manually in the CSS (`.gray .green-text{color: #bdbdbd;}`)